# How to properly install freetype2 devel package?

Tags: macos, terminal, homebrew, font, gcc

I wish to install `freetype 2 dev package` so I can use the `fontconvert` tool in `Adafruit-GFX-Library`

Here is what I get

```
$make fontconvert
fontconvert.c:22:10: fatal error: 'ft2build.h' file not found
#include <ft2build.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make: *** [fontconvert] Error 1
```

The community says that it because I haven't installed freetype 2 dev properly 
https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit-GFX-Library/issues/224

(I used `brew install freetype` to get freetype ?1?)

Tried to follow these instructions:

https://opensource.ncsa.illinois.edu/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=61604031

But it just created a folder with all the files - I think that they should be located at another directory - but don't know where..

Answer (score 1):

Found that I needed xcode to install all dependencies (prompted me when I opened xcode). It seems to be working now..